# onReceive BroadcastReceiver never called for explicit intent Android android Pie

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered a static receiver inside my Manifest but I don't know why my onReceive is never called. I have searched alot and checked several solutions but none of them worked as they are all identical.

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.androidsinglebcreceiver.show_toast"));
            }
        });
    
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String TAG = "Receiver";
    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "INTENT RECEIVED");
        
        Toast.makeText(context, "INTENT RECEIVED by Receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidsinglebcreceiver.show_toast" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to send your broadcast like this.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Receiver.class).setAction("com.example.androidsinglebcreceiver.show_toast"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need send Broadcast Like this and Provide complete Package name registration in manifest.

```
 Intent sendBcIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receiver.class);
                sendBcIntent.setAction("com.example.androidsinglebcreceiver.show_toast");
 sendBroadcast(sendBcIntent);
```